# MPI_Barrier and recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, mpi

I'm trying to use MPI_Barrier (OpenMPI) to force all the process to be in the same depth of a recursive call.

This is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

using namespace std;

void recursive_function(int,int,int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int rank, size;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    recursive_function(0,3,rank);

    MPI_Finalize();
}

void recursive_function(int depth, int limit, int rank) {
    printf("depth: %d, processor %d\n", depth, rank);

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if(depth == limit) return;
    else recursive_function(depth+1,limit,rank);
}
```

What I get is (running with mpirun -np 2 barrier)

```
depth: 0, processor 0
depth: 1, processor 0
depth: 2, processor 0
depth: 3, processor 0
depth: 0, processor 1
depth: 1, processor 1
depth: 2, processor 1
depth: 3, processor 1
```

While I would expect something like

```
depth: 0, processor 0
depth: 0, processor 1
depth: 1, processor 0
depth: 1, processor 1
depth: 2, processor 1
depth: 2, processor 0
depth: 3, processor 1
depth: 3, processor 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no guarantee that stdout among the MPI processes is ordered in any way.

That is, you need to have the processes communicate to prove that they are all at the same recursion depth. E.g. after the barrier each process != 0 sends a message to rank 0 which prints something.

Comment: +1, but perhaps it's worth ephasizing that the code looks correct in that no process can descend to the next level of recursion until all processes finished the current depth. It's just that the non-orderdness of stdout messes up the results on the screen.

Comment: thank you for you help. The problem was just the stdout. The code was in fact correct.